# Linux wrongly attempts to install onto USB drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

I'm attempting to install Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMD64) onto a Dell XPS 13 from a Kingston DataTraveler 100 G2 USB drive, with the bootable image created from LinuxLive.

I've successfully created the bootable USB and booted into Linux on the laptop from said USB, but when I attempt to install Linux, it says that it doesn't have enough space.

A few terminal commands were enough to verify that the issue is that it's not using the main computer hard drive; it's trying to install Linux from the USB drive onto the USB drive (which it thinks is the hard drive, I believe). My best guess is that I would need to change some setting indicating hard drive prioritization, but I'm totally lost as to what I need to do. How can I fix this?

Update: Ubuntu doesn't even seem to be able to find my hard drive:

[image: Figure 1. Ubuntu not recognizing hard drive]

Comment: What distro of Linux are you trying to install?  Can you post a screen shot, or your installation commands, in an update of your question?

Comment: Did you try to boot from a live-boot distro or trying to checking the settings of Bios ?

Comment: @ServiceManager I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktpo (AMD64) just using the standard installer -- that is, from the USB BIOS where it says "Try w/o installing, install, advanced options, etc) I select install and just follow normal procedure.

Comment: @GiaRui I am trying to boot from a live USB (created with LinuxLive), and I've been through all the settings of BIOS but don't know what I would need to change.

Comment: In the live-usb it shows the harddisk ? Maybe in the bios you have some settings like sata, which you might switch to ahci ?

Comment: @GiaRui updated -- the hard drive is not found by Ubuntu.

Comment: @BenjaminSpector Do you have any other software that you could boot from, to verify that the hard drive is not faulty, and can be detected?  Maybe GParted, or another Live distro which should be able to detect the drive?

Comment: If the bios setting and other distro didn't work. Perhaps you could try another live usb creation tool: E.g. Rufus, Unetbootin, Ubuntu startup disk creator, Universal usb installer, sardu, xboot etc.

Comment: I found some more time to mess around with it, and I was successfully able to boot the drive on a separate computer. I think it must be a problem with the laptop in some way (hardware or software), only I don't know what.